# How can i increase microphone volume beyond 100%

Tags: 20.04

The max volume of 100% is too quiet for me. Is there any setting/software i can use to increase the volume/gain?

Heres [my neofetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYltl.png) if needed

Comment: Is there any particular software you're trying to use with the microphone? Sometimes, individual applications like Audacity will have extra gain features.

Comment: Mainly steam and discord,

Comment: Two thins. 1. What Ubuntu version and type? 2. Additional info needs to be added to the question via edit not made as a comment.

Comment: You seemed to have just skipped over the last line of text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pulse Audio Volume Control

`sudo apt install pavucontrol`

[image: pavucontrol]

This allows you to set more than 100 percent for both input and output.

---

Commands to set N percent volume to your microphone

preparation: check the name of your microphone

`pactl list sources`

then

`pactl set-source-volume sourcename N%`

or

`pactl [options] set-(sink|source)-volume NAME|#N VOLUME [VOLUME ...] pactl [options] set-(sink-input|source-output)-volume #N VOLUME [VOLUME ...]`